# Mx records point to gmail; postfix mail sent direct from server marked as spam by gmail, yahoo

Tags: email, postfix, ubuntu-14.04, mx-record, gmail

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 server with postfix installed. However, I have set up the domain MX records to point to a Google apps' configuration, as per Google's instructions.

All works fine using email clients such as Thunderbird, Apple, Gmail om Android.

I would also like to forward system mail, such as cron output, to the gmail account. I have setup /etc/postfix/virtual for this. However, such mail gets marked as spam when it arrives at gmail. Same thing if I send to a Yahoo mail account.

Contents of /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = example.com
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = localhost, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
message_size_limit = 5120000
mailbox_size_limit = 5120000
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all

# to forward to another domain
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
inet_protocols = ipv4
```

Contents of /etc/postfix/virtual:

```
root root@example.com
postgres info@example.com
```

Contents of mail marked as spam by gmail:

```
Delivered-To: info@example.com
Received: by 2002:aed:2f41:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id l59-v6csp1151407qtd;
        Fri, 5 Oct 2018 17:01:30 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: ACcGV634DT4ke7ML+6DR3ZbuM0ejugIaHIVQ0A5hTlmrTZQGXwR7JjeJs48KeoNHV3o6zeeGjrp1
X-Received: by 2002:a50:8e56:: with SMTP id 22-v6mr17250946edx.101.1538784090699;
        Fri, 05 Oct 2018 17:01:30 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1538784090; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=LVJKKOt6I2s8vjwvsViL5b7wbkfbzHlQNGu9spySNuQpj8pDSyOa22qvFMw0hy9AL4
         qx8pOqm4iXiREJ6MK+tLEHQ6f1MehnnbxvKNyMwlpZ3GwKPaXYA3di5RZBeXpYJvqINP
         wppqIUo7IFGSQ4nxsZOABbGalB91piDYlEdUS7mZLTeq2krADoDLy1qZJVp0zXRLCXez
         6pASUh4UZv4MfyPOwXRM8pEkefEEEwj3pwW38luavDba9G9qzYaTS9DRR9zBYqI4NPII
         azKKqgqScaPJ/kj3wFCx7xkQ1Zkt/9qpL1/K09qpQfCBF09SVFrKnj5Jp6EtH+sCwbYx
         BK3Q==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=date:message-id:subject:to:from;
        bh=N+L1jS190l79xwwSepOlGcofnIXcnMDJmaZWohHFPME=;
        b=MfrDCRJLJYqKIOzGHDeEYD1OYxc/qQoVRALEo8KxIWVig51edIPOvy7eUgYljVUqss
         oUmQHIwgMiIjDIpnzG4qDAKoB9F9bWu0IhB8k900+iK1+ZH7sOKPFLwBHXtQhBp7SxOG
         0OEe5MVSCozsVGnQ6z2MDno/zsrG2uqmDQetL2g3ogCePP9kjzqA0KB2bLnPauktDD2T
         Eljz1nrGyJKcnAlb8JVMPD9DFggLBPpmk1yY8hahTmT91B/CVRMSNKXKRInH/msvJWIM
         0lOKkic1tb7mdmoAsCh+BfCiUtxsLk+ndK7TmOS03NzXvEPE7t0xU6I7G7qzeiiQwOre
         Nnyg==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       spf=neutral (google.com: 198.51.100.123 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of postgres@example.com) smtp.mailfrom=postgres@example.com
Return-Path: <postgres@example.com>
Received: from example.com ([198.51.100.123])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id o20-v6si8540152edr.352.2018.10.05.17.01.30
        for <info@example.com>;
        Fri, 05 Oct 2018 17:01:30 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 198.51.100.123 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of postgres@example.com) client-ip=198.51.100.123;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=neutral (google.com: 198.51.100.123 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of postgres@example.com) smtp.mailfrom=postgres@example.com
Received: by example.com (Postfix, from userid 105)
    id 0901860898; Sat,  6 Oct 2018 02:01:20 +0200 (CEST)
From: root@example.com (Cron Daemon)
To: postgres@example.com
Subject: Cron <postgres@treemapp> /var/lib/postgresql/pg_backup_rotated.sh
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ANSI_X3.4-1968
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/var/lib/postgresql>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=postgres>
Message-Id: <20181006000120.0901860898@example.com>
Date: Sat,  6 Oct 2018 02:01:20 +0200 (CEST)

*** Message Text ****
```

How to configure this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> spf=neutral (google.com: 198.51.100.123 is neither permitted nor
>   denied by best guess record for domain of postgres@example.com)

This is where to start: configure an SPF record for your domain.

> [Configure SPF records to work with G Suite](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786?hl=en)
>
> You can set up an SPF record to prevent spammers from using your
>   domain to send unauthorized emails, also called spoofing. Some mail
>   recipients require SPF. If you don’t add an SPF record for your
>   domain, your messages can be marked as spam or even bounce back.
>
> An SPF record lists the mail servers that are permitted to send email
>   on behalf of your domain. If a message is sent through an unauthorized
>   mail server, it’s reported and can be marked as spam.

Your SPF record would probably be like:

```
v=spf1 +ip4:198.51.100.123 include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

If that's not enough, the content might actually look like spam.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Esa. I've added a TXT to my domain with the SPF info you wrote. Guess I need to wait a bit to see if it's working.